# Where does nlpnet get it's metadata pickle file from?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I have installed nlpnet (http://nilc.icmc.usp.br/nlpnet/), but I can't locate the metadata_pos.pickle file it needs to run a part of speech tagger.  THis file does not appear to be on my machine, and is not included in the current github repository.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Just a blind shot, try `nltk.download('all')`. What is the error you're getting?

Comment: have you downloaded the models from http://nilc.icmc.usp.br/nlpnet/models.html ? BTW, how did you get pass the import errors: https://github.com/erickrf/nlpnet/issues/2?

Answer (score 0):

You need to download nlpnet-data(models for PoS, SRL and Dependency). It is available on http://nilc.icmc.usp.br/nlpnet/models.html . PoS tag model file Metadata_pos.pickle is available in http://nilc.icmc.usp.br/nlpnet/data/pos-pt.tgz

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the models from this page http://nilc.icmc.usp.br/nlpnet/models.html (either POS or SRL)

decompress the file in some folder, let's say '/Users/Downloads', then import in your code like that:

```
import nlpnet
nlpnet.set_data_dir('/Users/Downloads/pos-pt')

# Now you can start using it
tagger = nlpnet.POSTagger()
op = tagger.tag('texto em portugues')
```

Answer (score -1):

To train the model, you'll need examples with one sentence per line, having tokens and tags concatenated by an underscore character:

```
This_DT is_VBZ an_DT example_NN
```

Using this command with your corpus, you'll generate the data needed to use the POS tagger (including metadata_pos.pickle):

```
nlpnet-train.py pos --gold /path/to/training-data.txt
```

If you want to use an already trained model, they have one [here](http://143.107.183.175:21580/nlpnet/models.html). It was trained/evaluated with Mac-Morpho Corpus, a brazilian-portuguese news corpus so probably it won't work with other languages.